# If condition where date is not null and date is not '0000-00-00'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an `if` condition in JavaScript / PHP. I am getting a value for datefield shipdate. If `shipdate` is not null or empty or shipdate is not `'0000-00-00'` then `shipstatus` value should be `'Completed'` or else `'Pending'`. I am not getting the correct output.

Is there any mistake in the below script?

```
if ((shipdate.getValue() !== "") && (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00'))
        { 
    shipstatus.setValue('Completed');
    } else {
    shipstatus.setValue('Pending');
}
```

When i tried console.log, iam getting a value '

In console.log, iam getting a value like this '1899-11-29T18:30:00.000Z' for 'shipdate'. Iam not sure why?

Comment: You said : shipdate is NOT NULL or empty OR shipdate IS NOT '0000-00-00' but you use && in your if. Use || instead ?

Answer (score 2):

instead of and operator use OR operator in if statement

```
if ((shipdate.getValue() !== "") || (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00'))
```

Comment: (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00') is not taking. sometimes when field is null it writes '0000-00-00' to the mysql db. I need to validate for that too.

Comment: Ok, then add one more condition with OR operator (shipdate.getValue() !==null) this will not allow u to enter the if block, if the value of shipdate is null

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined php **empty** function.

```
if ( empty(shipdate.getValue()) ||  shipdate.getValue() == '0000-00-00')
{
    shipstatus.setValue('Pending');
}
else
{
    shipstatus.setValue('Completed');
}
```

Or you can use php **checkDate** function:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Comment: (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00') is not taking. sometimes when field is null it writes '0000-00-00' to the mysql db. I need to validate for that too.

Comment: @SanjuMenon you can use validatedate function.

Answer (score 1):

First check in alert or console.log() what value are you getting?
if you are getting `null` then put anothe condition

```
if ((shipdate.getValue() !== "") || (shipdate.getValue() !== NULL) ||(shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00'))
        { 
    shipstatus.setValue('Completed');
    } else {
    shipstatus.setValue('Pending');
}
```

Comment: (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00') is not taking. sometimes when field is null it writes '0000-00-00' to the mysql db. I need to validate for that too.

Comment: Or may be i just need to give (shipdate.getValue() !== '0') ?

Comment: check in console.log waht are you getting? and put  condition according to that

Comment: In console.log, iam getting a value like this '1899-11-29T18:30:00.000Z'. Its a date field, iam not sure what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
if (! (strlen(trim(shipdate.getValue())) == 0 || shipdate.getValue() == '0000-00-00'))
{ 
    shipstatus.setValue('Completed');
} else {
    shipstatus.setValue('Pending');
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: (shipdate.getValue() !== '0000-00-00') is not taking. sometimes when field is null it writes '0000-00-00' to the mysql db. I need to validate for that too.

Comment: Read me code : shipdate.getValue() == '0000-00-00'. You should test the 
opposite

Comment: In this case its taking the 0000-00-000 perfectly. But when date is entered also its showing as 'Pending' itself.

Comment: May be brace closing problem?